# How to connect with Azure Cluster Instances using Java

Tags: java, azure, containers, azure-cli, azure-container-instances

In AWS we have SSM which help us to connect to Cluster Instances and using SSM we got the data about the container in Java.
Same I am looking for Azure too. I want to connect with Azure Cluster Instances.
Is there any service in Azure available to get it done ?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure i find out we can achieve this goal using Azure VM.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/run-command